# How to split string to plain text, links and next line symbols?

Tags: javascript, regex

There is a string:

`"I have a link\n for you https://google.com.\n\nAlso http://some.net.\n\n\nSome text"`

I have regExp that splits the string to links and plain text

```
const text = 'I have a link\n for you https://google.com.\n\nAlso http://some.net.\n\n\nSome text';   
const regExp = /((?:http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(?:\/\S*)?)/g;
const textParts = text.split(regExp);
console.log(textParts);
```

In result I have:

`["I have a link↵ for you ", "https://google.com", ".↵↵Also ", "http://some.net", ".↵↵↵Some text"]`

**How should I modify the regExp to split also by next line symbol?**

**In result I need to have this**:

`["I have a link", "↵", "for you ", "https://google.com", ".", "↵", "↵", "Also ", "http://some.net", ".", "↵", "↵", "↵", "Some text"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter it using the following:

```
const text = 'I have a link\n for you https://google.com.\n\nAlso http://some.net.\n\n\nSome text';   
const regExp = /((?:http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3})|(\n)/g;
const textParts = text.split(regExp).filter(Boolean);
console.log(textParts);
```

I updated the end of the regex with an `OR` to check for 1 or more newlines. This resulted in some `undefined` results, but those are filtered out via the next line's `filter` call.

Without the `filter` you see:

`["I have a link", undefined, "↵", " for you ", "https://google.com", undefined, ".", undefined, "↵", "", undefined, "↵", "Also ", "http://some.net", undefined, ".", undefined, "↵", "", undefined, "↵", "", undefined, "↵", "Some text"]`

With the filter you see the expected output:

`["I have a link", "↵", " for you ", "https://google.com", ".", "↵", "↵", "Also ", "http://some.net", ".", "↵", "↵", "↵", "Some text"]`

Comment: I works but there is a note: If I have a few `↵` symbols one by another, in the result I get only one `↵` symbol. How can I fix it?

From this string 

`'I have a link\n for you https://google.com.\n\nAlso http://some.net.\n\n\nSome text'`

I have this result: 

`["I have a link", "↵", " for you ", "https://google.com", ".", "↵", "Also ", "http://some.net", ".", "↵", "Some text"]`

Comment: Sorry, I missed that part. The added `+` at the end was collapsing 1 or more newlines into a single value. Removing that includes each one separately.

Comment: Awesome! It works as I needed. But you wrote `cost` instead of `const` :)

Comment: Thanks! I was testing them as vars in the console and messed up changing them back :)